# ¿Porque mi consola me muestra empty en un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

buenas tardes a todos tengo un problema y eh tratado de buscar solución o tal vez sea cosa mía pero cuando quiero hacer una condicional dentro de un $.each cuando la condición[!es verdadera o falsa me muestra esto
esto es lo que estoy haciendo y me causa eso
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(index, item) {

                    if (item.visualizar == true) {
                        preview[index] = {
                            'Nombre_producto': item.Nombre_producto,
                            'Tipo_producto': item.Tipo_producto,
                            'Id': item.id,
                            'Precio_final': {
                                'lista': item.precios_nuevos
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                   //aqui me da ese empty de la imagen
                        noconfigurables[index]  = {
                            'Nombre_producto': item.Nombre_producto,
                            'Tipo_producto': item.Tipo_producto,
                            'Id': item.id,
                            'Precio_final': {
                                'lista': item.precios_nuevos
                            }
                        };
                        contador_productos_invisibles++;
                    }
                   
                })
```

Comment: Ese **empty** es un `console.log` a qué variable? Dónde y cómo declaras `preview` y `noconfigurables`?

Comment: ya actualice el formulario bro

Comment: El empty sale cuando tienes un array y no has seteado algunas posiciones. En tu caso, me estoy imaginando que en response tienes 5 elementos y solo el quinto tiene `visualizar = false`. Por eso tienes preview con 4 elementos, y nonconfigurables solo con el quinto elemento configurado, por eso el empty x 4 al inicio y el quinto lleno